# How to print with a serial port printer in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, printing, printer, port

I am completely clueless when it comes to printers, ports and things like that so I am just reading and trying to get a printer to work without getting a college degree haha...

Basically, I have a ORIENT BTP-2002NP (seems to be the same printer as SNBC BTP-2002NP) printer - it's a small thermal printer which I want to use to print basic stuff using PHP on my Ubuntu PC / Raspberry Pi OS server.

My main problem is - it's not a printer like usual printers, and I'm not that experienced with Ubuntu either - it does not get automatically detected, I can't just click "print" for it to work.

The device uses RS-232 cable, and I have it connected to USB through an adapter.

First I tried adding the printer - it was not detected. Then I tried adding it using CUPS - but ORIENT is not on the list of printers, and I don't have and wasn't able to find a PPD file. I was also unable to find any drivers for Ubuntu for this printer.

Then, my another idea was that I need to send information to print on the right tty which I think are ports?

I was able to find, that indeed the device gets connected and it ends up being ttyUSB0, and in lsusb it's displayed as Bus 001 Device 006: ID 067b:2303 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2303 Serial Port. According to some things I've found, I tried to cat and echo to that, to no avail. I did sudo su and tried cat /dev/ttyUSB0 as well as cat -v < /dev/ttyUSB0, and then in another terminal also did sudo su and tried different combinations of echo -e 'something' > /dev/ttyUSB0 - my echos "worked" with no errors or return message, but contrary to what guides and articles I found were saying, nothing showed up in the terminal with cat running.

At this point I'm kind of lost - I don't really grasp the concept of everything that's going on, and it seems like it's not something that I would be able to even really learn and understand in days or even weeks.

All I'm trying to do is print text from PHP to a thermal printer, but it's killing me... any form of help is really appreciated, I don't even know where to look for information at this point...

Comment: It's been a long time ago for me, but you probably need to study up on `lpadmin` (and `stty`).  The **/dev** directory will have have nodes for devices immediately connected and controllable by the CPU.  That would extend as far as the USB (bus) and the RS-232 adapter.  The serial printer is a *remote* device, and will not have a node in **/dev**.

Comment: Does this help at all ?  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117639/printing-on-serial-printer-via-cups

Comment: Verify that you have a BTP-2002NP **R3**, and not a R5, i.e. RS232 vs RS-485.  The serial port settings are 9600 baud, 8 bits/char, no parity, 1 stop bit, and ***hardware*** handshake.  You could try using a terminal emulation program, such as `minicom`, to send plain text to the serial terminal (and the connected remote printer).

Comment: @sawdust It's RS232 I'm sure, and yeah, 9600, 8, no parity and hardware handshake are right, I was able to print the specifications directly from the printer (it has such an option).

So far I was able to actually find PPD files which allowed me to install the printer, but there are 3 different ones ...2000NPP, NPU and NPS, I tried first 2 and had gotten some errors related to CUPS - first permission denied for the filter file, then 102 no such file or directory. Will try to debug it more this evening, as well as using minicom. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, so the PPD fils I got apparently are 32 bit so that's maybe why they didn't work - i get `execv failed: no such file or directory` in cups error log. I also tried minicom, but I am unable to find any information on... how to actually use it. I mean, i set up the connection and all, but now I have no clue how to use that connection. How do I actually go from setting up communication to printing something...

Comment: You will probably need to use a null-modem serial cable rather than a straight-through cable.  Does your USB-to-RS232 converter have a male DB-9 connector? Does the printer have female DB-25 connector?  This wiring should work: https://wiki.amigaos.net/w/images/5/54/04-db25-db9.png.

Comment: @sawdust USB goes to male DB-9, which goes into female DB-9 -> male DB-25, the printer has female DB-25. So, you're saying I just probably have the wrong DB-9 to DB-25 connector? Not USB to DB-9?

Comment: *"Not USB to DB-9?"* -- That would be a converter, you need that.  *"you're saying I just probably have the wrong DB-9 to DB-25 connector?"* -- Yes, very likely (but it's a *cable*).  There are many ways to wire those connectors together to make a cable.  That's why RS-232 is no longer used on consumer PCs; it's not plug-n-play.